# Complete type to incomplete type in C: C11 standard

Tags: c, types, standards, c11

Is there any situation where a complete type in a translation unit can become an incomplete type? The following statement in the footnote of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (Section 6.2.5) prompted this question.

> A type may be incomplete or complete throughout an entire translation unit, or it may change states at different points within a translation unit.

Examples abound for incomplete types becoming complete types in a translation unit. But I was wondering if the opposite scenario was ever possible. My gut would tell me it's not.

Comment: An untimely #undefine ?

Comment: @Jim #undefine happens during preprocessing. At that time, the notion of a type does not exist.

Comment: Then I don't see how it could happen.  (But I could well be wrong....)

Comment: @Jim: You mean `#undef`

Comment: #define #undefine #undef

Comment: @Jim: "error: macro names must be identifiers". (I'll show myself out.)

Comment: @KeithThompson  :)  I didn't think that would work.  Your brother Ken wrote too limited a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A example of a complicated situation would be the following

```
extern double A[];

double* f(void) {
  extern double A[5];
  enum { a = sizeof(A), }; //< A has complete type
  return A;
}

enum { b = sizeof(A), }; //< A has incomplete type: error

double A[5];

enum { c = sizeof(A), }; //< A has complete type
```

Comment: Nice application of scope.